# Show/plot images without resizing

Tags: r, image, plot, par

I'd like to plot several images in R with custom resolution.

Example:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
image(1:4,1:4,matrix(0,4,4))
image(1:2,1:2,matrix(1,2,2))
```

Instead of all having the same size (resolution) image 2 shoud be smaller
but still arranged with `par`.

I studied `ggplot`, `image`, `layout` and `par` and tried for hours without success.

Comment: what do you mean? you can use `par(mar = par('mar') * 2)` or something before drawing the second image

Comment: Good idea, but I have a lot of images with different sizes, like 1x1, 2x3, 4x4, 1x1. All should be arranged in a grid without being resized.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the gridExtra package, for example:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot() + 
 geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 4, ymin = 0, ymax = 4), color = "red", fill = "red")

p2 <- ggplot() + 
 geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 2, ymin = 0, ymax = 2), color = "orange", fill = "orange")

lay <- rbind(c(1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA),
             c(1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA),
             c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
             c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2))

grid.arrange(p1, p2, layout_matrix = lay)
```

This is a good resource: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html